# AngularJS - Data not rendering on 'data-class' attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat directive on a div and I'm trying to access information inside the repeated item, but for some reason `$index` renders OK in `data-position` but not on `data-class`. Is there something about this that prevents it from having AngularJS-bound data? The snippet bellow has me using an `index` property that I manually added to each element to see if it was an issue with `$index` but that didn't work.

For context, I'm handling these divs with some custom Javascript and the jQuery selector uses the data-class attribute.

```
<div id="dp-slider" birthday-container>
  <div class="dp_item" data-class="{{cumpleano.index}}" data-position="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="cumpleano in home.Cumpleanos" birthday-item>
    <div class="img-div"><img ng-src="{{cumpleano.Foto}}" class="dp-img"></div>
    <div class="text-div">
      <h5 class="slider-name">{{cumpleano.Title}}</h5>
      <div class="slider-sometext"> <span class="silder-p">{{cumpleano.Cumpleanos}}</span> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does `cumpleano.index` exist? since for `data-position` you output `$index`

Comment: did you try data-class="{{$index}}", as it is working

Comment: Can you also add the structure of your `cumpleano` object?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use ng-class with data-class instead of class with data-class

```
 <div data-class="{{cumpleano.index}}" data-position="{{$index}}"  birthday-item ng-repeat="cumpleano in home.Cumpleanos">
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Xypwep